# yeoman webapp - grunt fontawesome and bootstrap font files copy task

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs, yeoman, font-awesome, yeoman-generator

I have been working around with yeoman and I have generated a webapp with yeoman webapp generator and have added font-awesome and bootstrap-css with bower install. Also I have run `grunt bowerInstall` to update the `index.html` file.

Now when I launch the app with `grunt serve` everything works fine. Just a sample given below
[image: screen-grab desired output]

But when I do a grunt build and launch it with `grunt serve:dist` the icons are missing.
[image: screen-grab JavaScript errors in console]

I understand that the font files are not copied from the error logs in the console.
[image]
Looing into gruntjs file I guess Yeoman generates only tasks to copy the fonts under style/fonts of the app directory and I've to add my own copy task to copy font files.

```
{
    expand: true,
    dot: true,
    cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
    dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
    src: [
        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
        '.htaccess',
        'images/{,*/}*.webp',
        '{,*/}*.html',
        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
    ]
}
```

So the question is,

1. Why the task to copy bower_component/*/fonts/** to dist directory not included as this looks obvious considering the app fonts are copied using `styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*`
2. Is there a Yeoman/grunt specific configuration which can be included to copy this files.(Note: I already have a written a task to copy the font files as below. I would like to know whether there is a alternate way)

   ```
   {
       expand: true,
       dot: true,
       cwd: '<%= config.bower %>',
       flatten:true,
       dest: '<%= config.dist %>/fonts',
       src: [
           '{,*/}/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
       ]
   }
   ```

Thanks in advance.